# How can an iOS app reduce its memory footprint while it's already in background?

Tags: ios, memory, background, instruments

I use instruments to trace memory usage of some iOS app, such as Path,Instagram,Facebook. 
I find that while a foreground app take too much memory resulting very tight "Physical Memory Free". And while memory free reaches its lower boundary, maybe 10M, the system starts to reduce background app's memory size, for example Path drops memory from about **70M to 40M** progressively.

I am wondering how this happened, and I found that my own app doesn't behavior this way while in background. What I should do to make my app able to reduce it's memory footprint in background if needed?

Comment: Find cached data, images that could be re-created, things that you read from a file into memory, anything that you can create again if needed, and throw it away. Eventually iOS kills apps, and it kills those first that didn't give up memory.